# How to close all loaded forms using button

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have 4 forms that is open. I want to close all forms except the first form when i press button in Form4. See my sample code:

```
//Form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
    {
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }   
}
//Form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form3 frm = new Form3())
    {
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
//Form3
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form4 frm = new Form4())
    {
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
//Form4
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //So basically all forms are shown. What I want is when I press this button
    //all forms will close including this one except the first form.
}
```

What I'm thinking about is using FormClosing() event. Is it ideal or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code block

```
for (int i= App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; i>= 0; i--)
   App.Current.Windows[i].Close();
```

It works in my computer

App.Current.windows to get all windows, and then each window can be closed

Comment: I got an error, it says the name App does not exist in current context.

Comment: ShowDialog -> Show

Comment: already figured it out thanks for the idea. for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
                Application.OpenForms[i].Dispose();